# Same names in PCBs in array of pointers to Thread

Tags: c++, stack, kernel

I am writing a code for thread handling in C++. One instance of a Thread has a pointer to PCB structure and in the constructor of the Thread I just call `myPCB = new PCB(name, stackSize, timeSlice, this)`. It was all working just fine until I tried to make an array of pointers to Thread.

When I just make a pointer to thread and initialized it with new Thread(name, stackSize, timeSlice) the name in PCB of that Thread is appointed correctly.

But when I try it with an array of pointers all the PCBs have the same value for name variable.

I have checked and they are all diffrent PCBs (their IDs are diffrent). Their names get properly initialized in the constructor, but somewhere between the end of the constructor of the Nth and the end of the (N+1)th all names get the same value, that of N+1.

PCB constructor:

```
PCB::PCB(TName namee, StackSize stackSizee, Time timeSlicee,Thread *threadd){
    status = begging;

    id = genID++;
    if(namee) name = namee;
    else name = "Thread"+id;

    createStack(stackSizee);

    thread = threadd;

    timeSlice = timeSlicee;

    System::numberOfThreads++;
    System::allPCBQueue.add(this);

    waitingMe = new Queue();
    waitingFor = 0;

    semaphore = 0;

    sleepTime = -1;
    }

void PCB::createStack(StackSize stackSize){
    intOff;
    if(stackSize > maxStack) stack = new char[maxStack];
     else stack = new char[stackSize];

    newSS = FP_SEG(stack + stackSize);
    newSP = FP_OFF(stack + stackSize);
    asm{
      mov oldSS, ss
      mov oldSP, sp
      mov ss, newSS
      mov sp, newSP

      push ax; push bx; push cx; push dx; push es; push ds; push si; push di; push bp

      mov newSP, sp
      mov newSS, ss
      mov sp, oldSP
      mov ss, oldSS
    }

    stackPointer = MK_FP(newSS, newSP);
    intOn;
}
```

I figure its something with createStack() but I don't know what. All help is appreciated.

*Note: I currently don't have constant access to the internet so please don't get angry if I don't reply fastly. I will try to check on this question as much as I can.

EDITED:
PCB class definition:

```
class PCB
{
    static ID genID;

    char *stack;
    void *stackPointer;
    Thread *thread;

    TName name;
    ID id;

    Time timeSlice, sleepTime;
    Status status;

    Queue *waitingMe;
    PCB* waitingFor;

    KernelSem* semaphore;

    friend class Thread;

//  static unsigned newSS, newSP, oldSS, oldSP;

public:
    static StackSize maxStack;

    PCB(TName name, StackSize stackSize, Time timeSlice,Thread *thread);
    ~PCB(void);

    void runThread();

    ID getID(){
        return id;
    }
    TName getName(){
        return name;
    }

    void setStatus(Status status){
        this->status = status;
    }
    Status getStatus(){
        return status;
    }
    int getEnding(){
        if(status == ending) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
    int getBegging(){
        if(status == begging) return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    void createStack(StackSize stackSize);
    void* getStackPointer(){
        return stackPointer;
    }
    void setStack(void *newStackPointer){
        stackPointer = newStackPointer;
    }

    Time getTimeSlice(){return timeSlice;}

    Time getSleepTime(){return sleepTime;}
    void decrementSleepTime(){sleepTime--;}

    void setSemaphore(KernelSem* kersem){this->semaphore = kersem;}
    void resetSemphore(){this->semaphore = 0;}

    Thread* getThread(){return thread;}
};
```

Code where this happens:

```
Producer **pro = new Producer*[N];

for (i=0; i<N; i++){
    producerName[8]='0'+i;
    pro[i] = new Producer(buff, producerName ,'0'+i, TIME_SLICE);
    pro[i]->start();
}
```

It's the part of a test file that I got with this assignment. It mustn't be changed. But it is regular.
I have put

```
allPCBQueue->listAll()
```

after

```
pro[i] = new Producer(buff, producerName ,'0'+i, TIME_SLICE);
```

and I always get that all of the names are same. allPCBQueue is a simple list of PCBs

Comment: Why would it have something to do with the stack? Do you store the name on the thread stack? Can you please show the class definition of `PCB`?

Comment: Could you please also tell us what `TName` is?

Comment: I don't store the name on the thread stack. I did a lot of testing, and it seems to me that the createStack part is most critical. Edited the question including the class definition.

Comment: forgot about TName, sorry. typedef char* TName;

Comment: How is producername declared?

Comment: TName producerName = "producerx";

Comment: As a local variable, I guess...

Answer (score 3):

```
if(namee) name = namee;
else name = "Thread"+id;    <<< Doesn't do what you think it does.
```

"Thread" is a char *, adding a number to it will give you the pointer + offset.

You don't want to SWITCH to your new stack until AFTER you have created it. Instead of using push to store, just use something like this:

```
stackPointer = MK_FP(newSS, newSP);

unsigned *sp = reinterpret_cast<unsigned *>(stackPointer);

*--sp = 0;   // AX
*--sp = 0;   // BX
*--sp = 0;   // CX
*--sp = 0;   // DX
*--sp = default_ds;   // You'll have to dig this out with some inline assembler
*--sp = default_es;   // You'll have to dig this out with some inline assembler
*--sp = 0;   // SI
*--sp = 0;   // DI
*--sp = 0;   // BP

stackPointer = reinterpret_cast<void *>(sp);
```

[Of course, it would be easier to just make stackpointer a pointer to int in the first place].

Since the thread is starting from scratch, values of AX, BX, etc, doesn't matter. ES/DS may matter depending on what memory model you are using. Not pushing onto the stack also means you don't have to disable interrupts for this part - always a bonus.

Unfortunately, your code isn't showing what you are doing with "array of PCB's", so I can't say what' wrong there. And I'm sure someone says this should be a comment, not an answer, since it doesn't actually answer your question - but formatting code in comments is nearly hopeless...

Edit:

I'm guessing that "producername" is a local variable in your code that creates the threads. This won't work, but I think it's a bit difficult to dictate that the caller must ensure that the name stays forever, so I think what you should do is:

```
if(namee)
{
    size_t len = strlen(namee);
    char *name_buf = new char[len+1];
    strcpy(name_buf, namee);
    name = name_buf;
}
else
{
   // Make up some random name here.
}
```

Comment: The "thread"+id isn't the problem, I just left it like so until I solve the "same name" problem.

Let's say that I define a Test():Thread() class. When I run Test** array; array = new Test()*[N]; for(i=0;i<N;i++){ array[i] = new Test(names[i]);} where names is an array of names, all of the names of Tests are name[N-1]. (there are more parameters in the constructor, but I didn't include them to make things easier). basicaly, the instant I create an instance of the next member of array all behind it get its name. That's before doing anything with Tests, just creating them.

Comment: Sorry for the messy code in the last comment. Anyhow, I will most certainly look in to what you wrote about stack, but if I understood correctly it doesn't effect the name part? I have to do one task at the time or I would go crazy S:

Comment: Also, sorry for the late response. The libraries network stopped working.

Comment: Could you please post the actual code you are using for testing in your question, it's a bit hard to read in a comment. Just edit your question and add it there, please.

Comment: Producer is an expanded Thread class. Other parameters are not important as they are all signed properly. The funny thing is that all the other variables of the PCB (and by that Thread and Producer) are initialized correctly. Only names aren't

Answer (score 0):

The code was

```
name = namee
```

or

```
this->name = namee
```

I just made it

```
strcpy(name, namee)
```

and it works now.